# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: ':5ec5cc919efcf581eb692690' }" at path "_id" for model "Posts"

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, router

Checking the router on the server side it console logs the right values, only the follow error is popping up in here. Trying to build a counter that should update the value on the backend. But the problem I have is that value will not be stored in there. When using Postman the value will be stored successfully. What is the solution that can fix this issue.

```js
export const incrementProduct = (index, updateAmount, id) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(increment(index));
        try {
            axios.patch(`${API_URL}/:${id}`, {
            amount: updateAmount
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res.config);
        })
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
}


const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    amount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    editable: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    },
    data: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

// update 
router.patch('/:postId', async(req, res) => {
    console.log('update', req.params.postId + 'amount ' + req.body.amount)
    try {
        const updatedPost = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
            {_id: req.params.postId}, <--- this cause the console error...
            {$set: 
                { 
                    amount: req.body.amount
                },
            })
        console.log('try')
        res.json(updatedPost)
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err + 'test  ')
        res.json({ message: err })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove : in the patch url like this:

```js
axios.patch(`${API_URL}/${id}`
```

Also [findByIdAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) requires only the value of _id, so you can only pass the value like this:

```js
await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.postId, ...
```

`findByIdAndUpdate(id, ...)` is equivalent to `findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, ...)`.

Comment: @Frontendemployee what is the value of req.params.postId?

Comment: The problem is that it adds ':' before the _id....that cause the strange error.

Comment: @Frontendemployee because you send : in the patch url, check the updated answer please.